# Service Bus Not Reading from Subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am creating a sample Azure Service Bus application. I created a namespace, topic and Subscription. I have written test messages to the topic and if I go to the subscription in the portal, I see that I have a new message every time I write a new one using the writer application.

But when I go to pull the message, nothing is retrieved. In troubleshooting, I changed the subscription name to an incorrect value and received an error. I changed it back and I get no output and none of the messages are removed when I look in Azure portal. I'm stuck... this seems easy, but it isn't working.

```
string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://redacted for obvious reasons";

        SubscriptionClient Client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "NewOrders", "AllOrders");

        // Configure the callback options.
        OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
        options.AutoComplete = false;
        options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        Client.OnMessage((message) =>
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Body: " + message.GetBody<string>());

                message.Complete();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Indicates a problem, unlock message in subscription.
                message.Abandon();
            }
        }, options);
```

Comment: How your subscription AllOrders is configured? Can you share a repro of your code on GitHub?

Comment: Are you running a console app ? do you block the thread not to terminate the app ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not the code issue.  I create a demo to retrieve message from topic, it works correctly.
Before I try to retrieve message from topic, I send the message to the topic or make sure that there are messages for subscription. We could check that from the portal

[image]

Send message code demo.

```
 private static void SendMessages()
 {
    topicClient = TopicClient.Create(TopicName);

    List<BrokeredMessage> messageList = new List<BrokeredMessage>
    {
       CreateSampleMessage("1", "First message information"),
       CreateSampleMessage("2", "Second message information"),
       CreateSampleMessage("3", "Third message information")
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Sending messages to topic...");
    foreach (BrokeredMessage message in messageList)
    {
       while (true)
       {
          try
          {
             topicClient.Send(message);
          }
          catch (MessagingException e)
          {
              if (!e.IsTransient)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                  throw;
              }
           }
           Console.WriteLine($"Message sent: Id = {message.MessageId}, Body = {message.GetBody<string>()}");
           break;
        }
    }

      topicClient.Close();
}
```

I also try your mentioned code, it also works correctly for me.

[image]

[image]

We also could get the demo  project from the cloud Project from the template.  We also could get more info about [How to use Service Bus topics and subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) from the document.